# RxJs Skip Sample on first Emit, wait for one Observable to complete

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

**Question 1**

```
 combineLatest(this.layerService.layersData$, this.displayService.displayData$, this.dataSource.data$,
      (layer, display, data) => ({ layer, display, data }))
      .pipe(
        skipWhile(({ layer, display, data }) =>
          _.isEmpty(layer) || _.isEmpty(display) || _.isEmpty(data)),
        takeWhile(() => this.cacheService.isDirty()),
        sample(interval(2000)),
        map(result => {
          const layerFiltered = result.layer.filter(ly => result.display.findIndex(d => d.id === ly.id) !== -1);
          return { ...result, layer: layerFiltered };
        })
  )
  .subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result);
  });
```

I want to avoid sampling on very first emit and use the sampling after that.

By very first emit i mean, it was to able to get to the map function. 
Can it achieved without using external local variable?

---

**Question 2**

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.displayService.displayData$.delay(500).take(1).subscribe(data =>  this.displayMeta = data);

   this.layerService.getLayerData()
     .subscribe(layers => {
       this.layers = layers;
     });
}
```

I want layerService subscribe to wait till displayService completes, I can put the layerService subscribe logic inside displayService subscribe method, but that doesn't seem nice solution to the problem.

I want **this.displayService.......** code to be synchronous. 
I this also required once, not the take(1) operator.

---

**Question 3**

```
dirty = {};
fetchedData = {};
reportData$ = new BehaviorSubject({});

constructor(private dataSourceService: DataSourceService, private someService: SomeService) {
  const dataFetch$ = this.dataSourceService.data$
    .pipe(
      tap(dList => {
        // update dirty by comparing dList, if this.dirty has 3 keys and dList have two item then this.dirty length will be two
        this.dirty = dList.reduce((acc, et) => ({ ...acc, [et.id]: _.get(this.dirty, et.id, true) }), {});
      }),
      filter(dList => !_.isEmpty(dList)),
      map(dList => _.filter(dList, dL => this.dataSourceService.dirty[dL.id])),
      concatMap(dList => from(dList)),
      flatMap(dItem => this.someService.getDataFromApi(dItem), (item, data) => {
        return { id: item.id, data };
      }),
      tap(({ id, data }) => {
        this.fetchedData[id] = data;
        this.dirty[id] = false;
        this.dataSourceService.resetDirty(id);
      })
    );

  dataFetch$.merge(this.dataSourceService.data$)
    .subscribe(() => {
      this.fetchedData = _.pickBy(this.fetchedData, (__, key) => _.has(this.dirty, key));
      this.reportData$.next(this.fetchedData);
    });
}
```

The subscribe method should be called even if the filter return false. 
The problem with above approach is that subscribe will be called twice.

If dList is empty, dataFetch$ is not called, so the subscribe is called once but if its not empty then subscribe is called twice.

---

The design is if item are removed from this.dataSourceService.data$  one by one and finally this.dataSourceService.data$.length becomes 0, observable chain would not reach subscribe, in that case also make this.fetchedData = empty

As item from dataSourceService.data$ is removed corresponding item from this.fetchedData should be remove, I don't know which item is removed, thats why dirty flag, notice the first tap operation.
In the subscribe the dirtyList is used to update the fetchedData.

Answer (score 2):

**Question 1**

You may want to consider to create an Observable similar to the one you have already, but without the `sample` operator. Once you have such an Observable, you have the basic building block that allows you to get where you want to get.

The basic Observable should look something like

```
const basicObs = combineLatest(this.layerService.layersData$, this.displayService.displayData$, this.dataSource.data$,
      (layer, display, data) => ({ layer, display, data }))
      .pipe(
        skipWhile(({ layer, display, data }) =>
          _.isEmpty(layer) || _.isEmpty(display) || _.isEmpty(data)),
        takeWhile(() => this.cacheService.isDirty()),
        map(result => {
          const layerFiltered = result.layer.filter(ly => result.display.findIndex(d => d.id === ly.id) !== -1);
          return { ...result, layer: layerFiltered };
        })
  )
```

Then you can just combine the first emission of `basicObs` with all the following emissions using the `concat` operator. The code would look like

```
const firstNotification = basicObs.pipe(
  take(1)
);
const followingNotifications = basicObs.pipe(
  skip(1), // to avoid emitting the first element
  sample(interval(2000))
);

firstNotification.pipe(
  concat(followingNotifications)
)
.subscribe(result => console.log(result))
```

**Question 2**

If you want the subscription of `this.displayService.displayData$.delay(500).take(1)` to be executed before the subscription of `this.layerService.getLayerData()` is executed, then you may want ot try something like this

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.displayService.displayData$.pipe(
      delay(500),
      take(1),
      tap(data =>  this.displayMeta = data),  // this is the side effect that you have with the first subscription
      switchMap(() => this.layerService.getLayerData())
   )
     .subscribe(layers => {
       this.layers = layers;
     });
}
```

The key idea here is to use `switchMap` to switch from the first Observable, as soon as it emits, to the second one. Before switching though, via `tap` operator we run the side effect which was embedded in the subscription of `this.displayService.displayData$.delay(500).take(1)`.

Comment: what if for second question subscribe portion is huge.

Comment: i added one more question

Comment: what do you mean by "subscribe portion is huge"?

Comment: why don't you just remove `filter`?

Comment: subscribe portion is huge means if its non trival, and wouldn't the switchMap stop listening after one round, since there is take(1)

Comment: i have related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52412091/rxjs-if-else-logic